# How to load data to db from csv using LOAD DATA INFILE in drupal

Tags: mysql, drupal, drupal-6

I have tried the below code for laoding the inline file in drupal db

```
 $sql = "LOAD DATA INFILE '".db_escape_string($this->file_name).
         "' INTO TABLE `".$this->table_name.
         "` FIELDS TERMINATED BY '".db_escape_string($this->field_separate_char).
         "' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '".db_escape_string($this->field_enclose_char).
         "' ESCAPED BY '".db_escape_string($this->field_escape_char).
         "' ".
         ($this->use_csv_header ? " IGNORE 1 LINES " : "")
         ."(`".implode("`,`", $this->arr_csv_columns)."`)";
  $res = db_query($sql);
  $this->error = mysql_error();
```

I got the error as but the file was present in the folder

user warning: File 'http:\localhost\example\sites\default\files\example_1.csv' not found (Errcode: 22) query: LOAD DATA INFILE 'http://localhost/example/sites/default/files/example_1.csv' INTO TABLE `temp_21_10_2010_06_38_00` FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '\"' ESCAPED BY '\' IGNORE 1 LINES (`PROGRAMNAME`,`OFFLINE`,`ONLINE`,`INSTOCK`) in C:\wamp\www\example\sites\all\modules\importmodule\Quick_CSV_import.php on line 65.

On line 65 the above php code `$res = db_query($sql);` is present.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to specify the full/absolute or a relative path to your csv file not a URL

```
load data infile '/myproj/imports/example_1.csv' into table...

load data infile 'c:\\myproj\\imports\\example_1.csv' into table...
```

suggest you check the manual again http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html

Comment: The above same code works fine in php but i cannot get it through drupal.

Comment: You would have a different path from drupal than you would in a stand alone php script.

Comment: In Windows I had to use '/' slashes as path separator

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps is it due to [open_files_limit](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_open_files_limit) ?